# "Rails generate performance_test" not available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance-testing

I am currently trying to follow performance testing tutorial given in [Ruby on Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html). But I got stuck in the first step itself!

When I try to run the command given below i get an error,

Command:

```
$ rails generate performance_test homepage
```

Error I get:

```
Could not find generator 'performance_test'. Maybe you meant 'integration_test', 'resource_route' or 'coffee:assets'
```

I ran `"rails generator --help"` to see the possible files that can be generated and below is the output I got for that,

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 9465
Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Rails:
  assets
  channel
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  job
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  responders_controller
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  task

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Js:
  js:assets

RailsScript:
  rails_script:class
  rails_script:controller
  rails_script:element
  rails_script:install
  rails_script:utility

Responders:
  responders:install

Rspec:
  rspec:controller
  rspec:feature
  rspec:helper
  rspec:install
  rspec:integration
  rspec:job
  rspec:mailer
  rspec:model
  rspec:observer
  rspec:request
  rspec:scaffold
  rspec:view

SimpleCalendar:
  simple_calendar:views

TestUnit:
  test_unit:controller
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:helper
  test_unit:integration
  test_unit:job
  test_unit:mailer
  test_unit:model
  test_unit:plugin
  test_unit:scaffold
```

As seen above, a performance test unit is not defined there. Is this the case in RoR 5, or have I messed up the project and thereby not able to generate performance_test files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 4 removed performance_test from being a default. You can see in the Rails doc link you provided, it is for Rails 3.2.x

From https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest

> As of rails 4 performance tests are no longer part of the default stack.

On their github page there are instructions for adding it back, here are the relevant gems.

```
gem 'rails-perftest'
gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Comment: Thank you! I cannot up vote your answer yet as I'm a newbie.

Also, I did see that the doc was for 3.2.x but I got the same doc even when I searched for Rails 5.